# Failure to launch: App built in VS2013 can't run outside of Debug folder

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, compatibility

I am using VS2013 Pro on Win 7 and have an application that compiles and runs fine in the bin/x86/Debug folder (both with and without the debugger), BUT crashes instantly without a message, either onscreen or in the logs, if copied to any other folder.

Put another way, if the full path to the exe changes structure after compile in any way, it stops working. The names of the folders in the path can change, but not the structure.

I know this sounds like some sort of relative path thing, and maybe it is, but I have been unsuccessful in discovering what it is looking for.

An odd clue to what is happening may be this;  if I right-click the exe in a folder where it doesn't run, and choose 'Troubleshoot Compatibility', then 'Try recommended settings', and then 'Start the program...', it runs fine.

The app itself is .NET Framework 4 Winforms that references a few System.* DLLs and a DLL produced by a C++ project in the same VS2013 solution (that compiles without error).

So, what is going on here? I could use some ideas...

Comment: Do you copy the whole folder or just the .exe? If the exe depends on the dll, you have to copy the dll as well for obvious reasons.

Comment: I copy the whole Debug folder. I have tried adding the folder to c:\temp and c:\Program Files (x86) with the same negative results.

Comment: Try changing the target Platform for both your application and the dll. They should both match. Either 64bit or 32bit. 'Any CPU' has the tendency to break your application on 64bit machines, otherwise you might want to look into winDBG.

Comment: Hmmm... the target platform for the the C++ DLL is Win32 and the target for the app is x86. VS doesn't seem to offer x86 as a target choice for the DLL. The only choices are Win32, ARM, and x64. Another SO thread says that Win32 means the same thing as x86 in VS2012, so I assume it means the same in VS2013 as well. The app offers Any CPU, x64, and x86.

Comment: Are you trying to write something to the disk? If your app doesn't run as Administrator, you will not be able to write in Program Files and in any other folder on C other than your user folder. You can also make a check and see if works when you launch you exe with Run as Administrator.

Comment: Fails in the same manner when launched with Run as Administrator.  Moved the entire folder to 'My Documents' and it still fails.

Comment: Alin, you win.  The DLL was trying to write to a relative path that just didn't exist when the app was moved. Procmon showed it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the assemblies which are referenced by your application and if they are not the default .NET Assemblies like *System*, *System.Data* go to their properties (in property window) and select ***True*** for ***Copy Local*** option.

Make sure you have verified all third party/project assemblies which are referenced by your application as well as the assemblies which are referenced by your application's dependencies as per above check.

One more important thing if your application is referencing an assembly which is also referred by one of it dependent assembly make sure they are same otherwise at the time of building one assembly will replace another and your application might crash due to *System.BadImageFormatException* or *System.IOException*. In this scenario application can crash without leaving any trace.

I hope it will help.